# formatting multiple items together

Tags: css

Alright so I'm trying to format all these different items to have the same color instead of having to change them all separately. I'm following all the examples I can find on the internet but for some reason it isn't working. Please no salt when answering my question either, I'm just trying to find some help on finding this error.

```
HTML:
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="links"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="pictures"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>

CSS:
body, #header, #links, #main, #pictures, #footer{
     background-color:#cbebf6;
}
```

Comment: background color or text color, which?

Comment: You could give them all the same `class` identifier.

Comment: I'm trying the change the background color

Answer (score 0):

Style is ok, elements are empty - that's probably why you don't see the results.

Besides that you should use classes for common styles instead of ids

Comment: I have stuff in the items on the site just for demonstration purposes I don't have anything in them right now

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean you want to have a unique css selector for all elements. For that you should use a `class`

CSS:

```
.red{
     background-color:#cbebf6;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header" class="red"></div>
<div id="links" class="red"></div>
<div id="main" class="red"></div>
<div id="pictures" class="red"></div>
<div id="footer" class="red"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as  Drew Kennedy Suggested. Apply the same class to all of them.

```css
.bg-color  {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #cbebf6;;
}

 #header, #links, #main, #pictures, #footer {  /* Just for outline sake */
   width: 200px; 
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
   
   
   }
```

```html
<body class="bg-color">
<div id="header" class="bg-color"></div>
<div id="links" class="bg-color"></div>
<div id="main" class="bg-color"></div>
<div id="pictures" class="bg-color"></div>
<div id="footer" class="bg-color"></div>
  </body>
```